# Fwrite does nothing while trying to write html source as a string to a file

Tags: php, file-io, fwrite

```
public function save(){
        $currentPage    = $_SESSION['current_page'];
        $content        = $this->input->get_post("page_content");   // html content
        $path           = $this->paths('pages');    
        $page           = $this->pages->db_get(array("id"=>$currentPage), true);

        //echo $path . $page['filename'];
        if(!is_dir($path)){
            $fileHandle = fopen($path . $page['filename'] , 'w');
            if(!fwrite($fileHandle, $content)) {
                $this->errors[] = "Error saving page";
            }
            fclose($fileHandle);
        }


echo json_encode($this->errors);
}
```

I receieve a html source file via ajax POST request which then i wish to write to a file as a string.
The commented line would echo */home/sajt/public_html/application/data/users/kobra@kobras.net/websites/kobra/pages/glavna.php* which exists on the server. I believe and have checked that $path, $page and $content have the correct values needed since echoing the $path . $page['filename'] returns a valid path to the file, but still nothing happens, that is nothing is being written.
What am i missing here?

Parent Directory permissions :

```
drwx------    5 sajt       sajt             4096 Aug  9 04:20 .
drwx------    3 sajt       sajt             4096 Aug  9 04:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 sajt       sajt             4096 Aug  9 04:20 header
drwxr-xr-x    2 sajt       sajt             4096 Aug  9 04:20 pages
drwxr-xr-x    2 sajt       sajt             4096 Aug  9 04:20 uploads
```

Directory "pages" permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 sajt       sajt             4096 Aug  9 04:20 .
drwx------    5 sajt       sajt             4096 Aug  9 04:20 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 sajt       sajt                0 Aug  9 13:20 glavna.php
-rw-r--r--    1 sajt       sajt             1450 Aug  9 04:20 kontakt.php
```

Comment: Have you checked file / folder permissions? Are you running the script on localhost or on a webserver?

Comment: Do you have write permissions to that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(!is_dir($path)){
```

you explicitly tell the script to skip the whole fopen/fwrite business, because as your code is written, whatever is in $path HAS to be a directory.

Most likely you simply want

```
if (is_dir($path)) {
    ^--- no !
```

Comment: omg i can't believe it. I guess i need some sleep. Thanks marc who knows when i would have noticed :D